# Angular custom validator directive issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-validation

I am having some troubles with my custom directive and it doesn't seem to be registered for some reason. I have added the following custom directive into app.module's `declarations` array. So I guess it must be something else that I am still missing.

Also, interestingly if I do `form.addControl('name', new FormControl('', [noWhitespaceValidator()]));`, then the validation works fine, but when I switch to using custom attribute `[myNoWhitespace]`, it fails. I doubt if it's really caused by using Reactive From approach in this case here, but I am not too sure.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myNoWhitespace]',
    providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: NoWhitespaceDirective, multi: true }]
})
export class NoWhitespaceDirective implements Validator {
    validator: ValidatorFn;

    constructor() {
        this.validator = noWhitespaceValidator();
    }

    validate(control: AbstractControl) {
        return this.validator(control);
    }
}

export function noWhitespaceValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
        const isWhitespace = (control.value || '').trim().length === 0;
        return !isWhitespace ? null : { 'whitespace': '' };
    };
}

<input type="text" id="name" formControlName="name" name="name" myNoWhitespace>
```

Comment: Can you explain what `it fails` means?

Comment: Do you have the directive listed in `declarations` of the ngModule?

Comment: @cgTag means no validation happens. I tried to set a break point with the debugger in the directive code, it didn't get called at all

Comment: @cgTag yes, added to declarations, that's what I've done. I mentioned it at the beginning of my post

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: @cgTag yeah it's really odd to me as well... :(

Comment: This is a long shot, but maybe it's a dependency issue. Try this  `useExisting: forwardRef(function () { return NoWhitespaceDirective; })`

Comment: @cgTag Still no difference. But thanks anyway.

Comment: This is how I do my validators. It should be working. Make sure you import the module the validator is exported from.

Comment: You are mixing template-driven form validator with reactive form. For reactive form. you can define validator along with the form control.

Comment: @cgTag Thanks for that. But the validator isn't using a feature module though.

Comment: @Pengyy Yeah, possibly. That's why it works fine if I define validators when adding the form controls. I think I am going with this one for the time being.

Comment: I don't use it this way, but it's working fine here. see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zymgaf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts